# How do I scrape data in an html(xml) table row and the values of its children using xpath based on a text string?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

Here is the html I am trying to scrape using Xpath:

```
<table class="ClassGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3">
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1">Address 123
                <br>
                <br><a target="_blank" class="gridDirections" href="/Classes/Directions.aspx#104">Directions</a></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
          <div class="ClassGridBox2">12/12/2018</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl3_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4233&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
          <div class="ClassGridBox2">1/24/2019</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl4_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4306&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 4</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBoxNone"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 18</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl6_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4346&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Thursday, August 30</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl7_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4313&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, September 8</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl8_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4330&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, September 18</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl9_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4331&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3">
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1">Address 0000
                <br><a target="_blank" class="gridDirections" href="/Classes/Directions.aspx#190">Directions</a></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, July 21</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl11_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4242&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, August 28</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl12_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4243&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, September 25</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl13_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4271&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3">
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1">Address 456
                <br><a target="_blank" class="gridDirections" href="/Classes/Directions.aspx#69">Directions</a></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Wednesday, August 1</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl15_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4276&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 25</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl16_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4277&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Thursday, September 13</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl17_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4348&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, October 6</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl18_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4278&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Wednesday, October 31</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl19_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4279&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, November 17</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl20_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4280&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3">
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1">Address 789
                <br><a target="_blank" class="gridDirections" href="/Classes/Directions.aspx#223">Directions</a></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 4</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl22_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4347&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 18</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl23_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4305&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1">
            <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow2">
            <div class="ClassGridBox2">Thursday, September 20</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ClassGridRow3">
            <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl24_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4332&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3">
            <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I am trying to return the value of **ClassGridRow1**, **ClassGridRow2** and **ClassGridBox3** if **ClassGridRow1** contains the text string

> "Address 123"

for example. So far, I have had no luck retrieving anything but just the context node's contents. Can anyone please assist? Most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have all XPath features available you could select the `<div class="ClassGridBox1">` node and mangle the `text()` with a [regex `fn:replace`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html):

```
//tbody/tr/td/div[@class="ClassGridBox1"]/[replace(text(),'(^[a-zA-Z.-]+ [0-9]+).*','$1', 's')]
```

[**Demo**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctable%20class%3D%22ClassGrid%22%20cellspacing%3D%220%22%20cellpadding%3D%220%22%20border%3D%220%22%20id%3D%22_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses%22%20style%3D%22border-collapse%3Acollapse%3B%22%3E%0A%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow1%22%20colspan%3D%223%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow1%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox1%22%3EAddress%20123%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%3Ca%20target%3D%22_blank%22%20class%3D%22gridDirections%22%20href%3D%22%2FClasses%2FDirections.aspx%23104%22%3EDirections%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow2%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox2%22%3E12%2F12%2F2018%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow3%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox3%22%3E%3Ca%20id%3D%22_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl3_hplAddToCart%22%20class%3D%22whitelight%22%20href%3D%22%2Fvalidate.aspx%3FClassID1%3D4233%26amp%3BClassID2%3D0%22%3EBook%20Now%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow1%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox1%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow2%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox2%22%3E1%2F24%2F2019%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow3%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox3%22%3E%3Ca%20id%3D%22_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl4_hplAddToCart%22%20class%3D%22whitelight%22%20href%3D%22%2Fvalidate.aspx%3FClassID1%3D4306%26amp%3BClassID2%3D0%22%3EBook%20Now%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow1%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox1%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow2%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox2%22%3ESaturday%2C%20August%204%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow3%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBoxNone%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow1%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox1%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow2%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox2%22%3ESaturday%2C%20August%2018%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20class%3D%22ClassGridRow3%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ClassGridBox3%22%3E%3Ca%20id%3D%22_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl6_hplAddToCart%22%20class%3D%22whitelight%22%20href%3D%22%2Fvalidate.aspx%3FClassID1%3D4346%26amp%3BClassID2%3D0%22%3EBook%20Now%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22ClassGridBox1%22%5D%2F%5Breplace(text()%2C'(%5E%5Ba-zA-Z.-%5D%2B%20%5B0-9%5D%2B).*'%2C'%241'%2C%20's')%5D&=%2F%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22ClassGridBox1%22%5D%2F%5Breplace(text()%2C'(%5E%5Ba-zA-Z.-%5D%2B%20%5B0-9%5D%2B).*'%2C'%241'%2C%20's')%5D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2&print-type-annotations=true)

Or a bit relaxed with some post text processing:

```
//tbody/tr/td/div[@class="ClassGridBox1"]/text()
```